# Fabric.js align right and underline not working together

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I have 2 button first to align text to 'right' and second one is to set underline.

**First Problem ::**
But, if text is Aligned to right and i click underline button i get something like below,

**Second Problem ::**
if text is Aligned to right or left[another button created] then for both the button text is moved to right only, m i creating text wrong??

Add text method is :

```
hw[i] = new fabric.Text($(this).val(), {
            left : drawleft,
            top : drawtop,
            fontSize : 20,
            textAlign: 'center'
        });
```

Jquery code is ::

```
    $('#font_un').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
         ++index;
   action=true;  

        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

        if (!obj)
            return;

        if (un_flag == 0) {

            obj.set('textDecoration', 'underline');
            un_flag = 1;
        } else {
            obj.set('textDecoration', '');
            un_flag = 0;
        }

        canvas.renderAll();

    });

$(document).on("click","#font-right",function(event){

        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
         ++index;
   action=true;  

        event.stopPropagation();
        if (!obj)
            return;

        obj.set('textAlign', 'right');

        canvas.renderAll();
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved My Problem , I was using Wrong Method it should be

```
obj.set('originX', 'center').setCoords();

        canvas.renderAll();
```